# Add "ng-class" on parent of selected element's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So another question related to `ng-class` is..

Adding class to the `<ul>` on the click of `<button>` present in its `<li>`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JfeLz/9/)**

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<section ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in model.items" class="commonClass">{{ item.name }}</li>
        <li><button>
        active
        </button></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in model.items" class="commonClass">{{ item.name }}</li>
        <li><button>
        active
        </button></li>
    </ul>
</section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.model = {
        selected: null,
        items : [
            {name: "Apple"}, 
            {name: "Banana"}, 
            {name: "California"}
         ]
    };
})
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There is no `ng-class` directive anywhere in your demo code and your buttons are not within the `ng-repeat` scope so you can freely access the `<ul>` from the `<li>` with model or scope.

Comment: this `ul` is actually coming from json so that is also repeating itself

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
You ll find what you need at bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.uls = [{model: { selected: null, items: [{ name: "Apple" }, { name: "Banana" }, { name: "California" }] }}, {model:{ selected: null, items: [{ name: "Apple" }, { name: "Banana" }, { name: "California" }] }}];

  /* $scope.model = {
    selected: null,
    items: [{
      name: "Apple"
    }, {
      name: "Banana"
    }, {
      name: "California"
    }]
  }; */
})
```

```css
.on {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-class="{'on': ul.onIsOn}" ng-repeat="ul in uls">
      <li ng-repeat="item in ul.model.items" class="commonClass">{{ item.name }}</li>
      <li>
        <button ng-click="ul.onIsOn = !ul.onIsOn">
          active
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: great.. this works.. 1 more query.. can i change the text over button to "inactive" ?

Comment: replace active with  {{ onIsOn ? "Inactive" : "Active"}}